# Catalog price rule for all products with qty > 0

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules

Is there a way to apply a catalog price rule to all products with qty > 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the best solution , but an alternative manual solution.

you can **create a textfield attribute** [ assume : brand] and assign to **attribute set**.

you can go to Catalog > Manage Products & in you can select **From: 1** under Qty as below image.

[image]

than you can **search** products and than you can **select all** Products and go to **Actions** and **update attributes** and you can give **value = 1** for brand and save it.

than go to **Promotions > catalog > price rules > add new rule.**

under conditions > select **Brand is 1** & save it.

[image]